# ASP.NET MVC Reports wit PDF and EXCEL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, pdf, reportviewer

I Would like to get references on best way to generate reports in an MVC application that allows me to export the results to PDF and EXCEL.

I am currently creating a VIEW, filling a MODEL with data, and exporting view to PDF, using ROTATIVA.

But I have doubts if this is the best way to develop reports in MVC structure.

I checked the options in this post:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94696/relat%C3%B3rios-com-asp-net-mvc

But neither of them works with Excel.

I also found out that I can still use RDLC in MVC at this link: http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html

But I can not add RDLC files in my project. I have the Report templates in my visual studio.

I have already installed ReportViewerForMVC in my project, but I'm still without the RDLC templates.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What issue do you have with Rotativa? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not having problems with Rotativa, but I'm considering replace it by some tool that allows me to export data to EXCEL and PDF, just like ReportViewer and RDLC in ASP.NET WebForms. Rotativa works only with PDF, right?